# Shift the x axis to the left

Tags: r, plot

The labels I have on the x-axis do not line up correctly and I would like to shift them to the left. The labels are diagonal and slightly off from what they align with

```
#reproducible
r1 = sample(1:100,20,replace=T)
r2 = sample(1:100,20,replace=T)
fake_mainbroca = cbind(r1,r2)
colnames(fake_mainbroca)= c('a1','a2','a3','a4','a5','a6','a7','a8','a9','a10','a11','a12','a13','a14','a15','a16','a17','a18','a19','a20'
fake_ants = fakemainbroca[,15:20]

multi_ant_means <-c()
multi_ant_errors <-c()

for(Jloop in 1:dim(ants)[2]){

        ind_ant_data <- fake_ants[,Jloop]
        ant_pres <- fake_mainbroca$Attack_count[ind_ant_data > 0]
        ant_not_pres <- fake_mainbroca$Attack_count[ind_ant_data == 0]

        means <- c(mean(ant_pres),mean(ant_not_pres))
        errors <- c(err(ant_pres), err(ant_not_pres))

                    multi_ant_means <- c(multi_ant_means, means)
                    multi_ant_errors <- c(multi_ant_errors, errors)
}

x_axis_names <-c('WA present','WA absent', 'PM present', 'PM absent', 'MF present', 'MF absent', 'BH present','BH absent', 'SI invicta present', 'SI invicta absent' )


index_ac <- seq(1,length(multi_ant_means),1) 

par(mfrow=c(1,1))
attack_count_graph <- 

  plot(index_ac, multi_ant_means, ylim=c(0.5,2.5),xaxt="n",xlab="",pch=19,ylab="",yaxt="n")
  arrows(index_ac, multi_ant_means + multi_ant_errors, index_ac, multi_ant_means - multi_ant_errors, code=3,length=0.0,angle=90)
  text(x = seq(1,10, by=1), par('usr')[3]-0.3, labels=x_axis_names, srt=45, pos = 1, xpd=TRUE)
  axis(2,las=2)
  mtext("Mean CBB Attacks (counts)",side=2,line=2.5)
```

Comment: Hi @Jannice Newson, thanks for trying to make a reproducible answer.  However, can you review your code and make sure it is entirely reproducible (i.e. in a new R session)?  There are errors for one trying to run what you have posted.

Comment: Yes, I just ran it in a new session and I see that it does not work. I also do not know how to fix it.

Comment: Can you post the error output you get when you run your code?  That way you can fix each error as it arises and modify your post each time to reflect what you've tried thus far.